# MATLAB : right click behind the window when closing a figure with a 'ButtonDownFcn'

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having a specific issue that can be summed up in the little script below. Obviously it's part of a bigger project.

This script (call it 'my_test.m') opens a figure and displays an image. A 'ButtonDownFcn' is set so that **the figure is closed when the image is right-clicked**.

The behavior that annoys me is that after the figure is closed, **the right-click is activated on whatever-is-behind-the-figure**. As if there had never been a figure there.

Would you have an idea to prevent this behavior and tell the operating system to ignore the right click ?
Thanks in advance.

Configuration:

- Matlab : R2011b - 64bit
- Windows 7

Script:

```
function my_test()
handles.f=figure;
handles.a=imshow(ones(400));
set(handles.a,'ButtonDownFcn',{@image_ButtonDownFcn});
guidata(handles.f,handles);

function image_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata)
handles=guidata(hObject);
switch lower(get(handles.f, 'selectiontype'))
  case 'alt' % right click
    close(handles.f);
end
```

Comment: do I get you right: using your example, the following happens: I click on the image (rigth-click), the figure closes AND after that - let's call it "another" - right click is fired?

Comment: I think the windowButtonUpFcn/mouseReleaseCallback is fired behind the figure as it closes on button down, you could press and hold the mouse button to check, the figure will close when the button is pressed, but whatever is behind will not be clicked until the button is released

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I didn't notice that the annoying behavior occurs only if I keep the right-click long enough for the figure to close before releasing the right-click. In other words, if I right-click fast enough, it works fine. I'll try to look for a "mouse release callback". Thanks !

Comment: well, this is a very nice question! but just one thing: you should put the awnser - although you found it by yourself - into a "real" awnser and then accept it by yourself! (you will get additional points for that ;-)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Lucius Domitius Ahenobarbus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572698/lucius-domitius-ahenobarbus) and [RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115638/rtl), I modified the code and it works. I just replaced this line :

```
close(handles.f);
```

...by this one :

```
set(handles.f,'WindowButtonUpFcn','close(gcf);');
```

The idea is to use the 'WindowButtonUpFcn' of the figure (images or axes don't have such callbacks) so that nothing happens on mouse click but then the figure closes itself on mouse click release. There might be neater solutions ?